# Nginx "auth_basic" string encoding

Tags: nginx, configuration, http-headers, encoding, charset

What is the right encoding/charset in nginx configuration file to display accentuated characters in HTTP authentication message ?

For example, this conf file :

```
server {
...
    location / {
        auth_basic           "Zone sécurisée";
        auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;
    }
}
```

Is displaying in Firefox' prompt window :

> "Zone sÃ©curisÃ©e"

No real solution or explanation found on the web. I tried to replace `é` in conf file by `Ã©`, by `&amp;`, by `&#233`, by `=C3=A9` or adding `charset utf-8` directive or `=?UTF-8?` at the beginning of the string but nothing works !

[Official nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html#auth_basic) doc, talking about a "string" without more explanation about encoding of accentuated characters.

NB : I have no problem with similar `.htaccess` file for Apache

Comment: Did you check that your editor actually saves the files in UTF8 encoding?

Comment: Yes, it saved in `UTF-8` and I tried `UTF-8 with BOM` but it worst !

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 7617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617#section-3) Section 3

> The **'realm'** parameter carries data that can be considered textual;
> however, `[RFC7235] does not define a way to reliably transport non-
> US-ASCII characters.  This is a known issue that would need to be
> addressed in a revision to that specification.

`realm` parameter is the string you put in `auth_basic` directive. So, can't suggest anything, but stick to ASCII.